# FT450D no cw tx unless ppt is held

Tags: cw, transmitter

FT450D in cw mode does not transmit unless PTT is actuated.  "BK-IN" not in display despite pressing function followed by vox/store button.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: What do you mean that PTT has to be actuated?  Do you need to squeeze the PTT button on the microphone to send Morse code?  How are you keying the transmitter, through the key jack on the back panel?

Comment: Straight Key in front jack, mode is USB CW. PPT has to be squeezed to key the TX

Answer (score 1):

According to page 46 of the manual, you must press the `F` button followed by the `STO/VOX` button to put the rig in break-in mode, which is indicated by the "BK-IN" icon in the display.

Comment: Many thanks for that tip. now have "BK-IN" in display and CW TX now working! Gordon Jackson G4FPK

Comment: I'm glad that the tip helped!  If an answer was helpful then please consider upvoting it, and if you feel that your question was answered, then please consider clicking the check mark next to the answer.